# New Thread not working with JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe

I have made a class that displays a series of images to create an animation. I would like the animation to take place on a separate thread than the rest of the program. However, when I try to start the animation class, I get an error.

**This is some of the animation class** (There is more but is is irrelevant)**:**

```
    /**
     * Starts a new thread to play the animation on
     */
    public void start()
    {
        playing = true;
        animateThread = (new Thread(() -> run()));
        animateThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Will go through sprites and display the images
     */
    public void run()
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (playing)
        {
            if (index > sprites.length)
            {
                index = 0;
            }
            try
            {
                g.drawImage(sprites[index].getImage(), x, y, null);
                animateThread.sleep(speed);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            index++;
        }
    }
```

I have also attempted at making the animation class Runnable, then making the whole object a new Thread but I received the same error.

**This is the class which holds the JFrame and starts the animation** (There is more but is is irrelevant)**:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AnimationTester tester = new AnimationTester();
        tester.frame.setResizable(false);
        tester.frame.setTitle("Tester");
        tester.frame.add(tester);
        tester.frame.pack();

        tester.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        tester.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        tester.frame.setVisible(true);

        //Make the window not have to be clicked on to get input (Set is as the main focus when it begins)
        tester.requestFocusInWindow();

        //Start the program
        tester.start();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        createGraphics();
        animation.start();
    }


    public void createGraphics()
    {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        //Checks to see if the BufferStrategy has already been created, it only needs to be created once
        if (bs == null)
        {
            //Always do triple buffering (put 3 in the param)
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }


        //Links the bufferStrategy and graphics, creating a graphics context
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        try
        {
            animation = new Animation(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/SpriteSheet.jpg")), 16, 2, 200, 250, 250, 2.0);
            animation.addGraphics(g);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not really how `BufferStrategy` works, instead of using `createGraphics`, you should be calling it to update the state and render it to the screen

Comment: What is the error you're getting?
Sidenote: there is a bug in "if (index > sprites.length)", as this allows index to be the equal to sprites.length, which when used to access the sprites in "sprites[index]" will lead to an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
Should change it to "if (index == sprites.length)"

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how `BufferStrategy` works, instead of using `createGraphics`, you should be calling it to update the state and render it to the screen

So, in your `Thread`, it should be updating the state in some way and call some "render" method which would get the next page, render the state and push that state to the screen.

Take a closer look at [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) for more details about how it's suppose to work

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516191/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-createbufferstrategy/35516500#35516500)