# Java - how to create bufferedStrategy to jframe

Tags: java, graphics, render, bufferstrategy

i'm new using **java2D** and **java Graphics** i have some issue while using `BufferStrategy` in java, i tried solve but it doesn't work, while creating a `BufferStrategy` it gives errors like this...

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer
at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Component.java:4006)
at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:3980)
at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:4503)
at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3857)
at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:194)
at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3781)
at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:169)
at code.Main.render(Main.java:84)
at code.Main.run(Main.java:31)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 24 seconds)
```

i'm getting most of my code for this project in [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idb6-Zfdq2Q&index=5&list=PLah6faXAgguMnTBs3JnEJY0shAc18XYQZ), `"at code.Main.render(Main.java:84)"` points to this render method

```
private void render()
{
   bufferStrategy= display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy(); //getting bufferstrategy
   if(bufferStrategy==null)
   {
       display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);// creating bufferstrategy, output says error in this line
       return;
   }
   g= bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics(); 
   g.fillRect(1,1,width,height);//draw a rectangle
   bufferStrategy.show();//show all things (build-in method)
   g.dispose();
}
```

and **second error** is when `render()` method is called

```
public void run()                           //override run to Runnable
{
    initialize();                           //create and initialize Display frame and canvas

    while (runningStatues)                  //works when game is already running
    {
        tick();                             //update variables, have no code here
        render();                           // here is contain error
    }
    stop();
}
```

i think it's too complicate for me, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Component must have a valid peer

What this is (trying) to tell you is, you've tried to create a `BufferStrategy` before the underlying window has been realised on the screen - this means, attached to a native peer.  In AWT/Swing, a window becomes realised when it is either first resized or made visible.

So, as a generalised suggestion, make the window visible BEFORE you try creating the `BufferStrategy`

I would, highly, recommend that you take a look at the [JavaDocs for `BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) as it has an excellent example of the recommended workflow, from which you can base your solution.

I would also recommend having a look at the [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) trail, as it contains a number of runnable examples which you can play around with

I would also recommend NOT using the frame's `BufferStrategy`, but instead using a `Canvas`, which is added to the frame, this will prevent you from painting beneath the window's borders

You might consider having a look at something like [What is the correct way to use createBufferStrategy()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516191/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-createbufferstrategy/35516500#35516500) for a runnable example

Comment: i read the links, i'm using canvas to create `BufferStrategy`, and my frame is created before creating `BufferStrategy`, it creates frame in `initialize()` before calling `render()` that creates `BufferStrategy`

Comment: i would ask if there is an easier way to render a simple rectangle instead of using `BufferStrategy`?

Comment: oh, i found the bug! in `Display` class(contains frame), i was trying create buffers before adding canvas to my `JFrame`, i guess you want to tell me this by >"make the window (visible) BEFORE you create the `BufferStrategy`", i thought you mean `frame.setVisible(true);`. thanks for your help, i wasn't understand till i read your answer in depth, really thank you =)

Comment: @mhamadarsalan Yeah, I was suggesting `setVisible`, but so long as the window has been attached to a native peer it should work (`setVisible` and I think `setSize` trigger the creation of the native peer)